# How to remove the title, author names, institutions, date from appearing at each page in lyx

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am using beamer in lyx. The preamble I have is printed below :

```
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \useoutertheme{wuerzburg}
    \useinnertheme[outline]{chamfered}
    \usecolortheme{shark}
```

And in each page, I have the titles appearing in the top, and authors, date etc, appearing at the bottom. It's taking too much space, is there anyway I can remove them ?

Comment: You could always use another theme without these features

Answer (score 1):

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
```